# pass char array properly to templated method

Tags: c++, enums, c++17

I have some class with enum variable and I wants to stringify that enum. For that reason I added **typeValue** with stringified values. Also I added separate class for getting stringified values but I can't pass variables in correct way.
Code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

#define stringify(name) #name

struct MyClass
{
    enum class TYPE
    {
        UNKNOWN = 0,
        CLIENT,
        SERVER
    };
    
    MyClass(TYPE t)
        :_type(t)
    {       
    }
    
    TYPE type()
    {
        return _type;
    }

    inline static const char* typeValue[10] =
    {
        stringify(TYPE::UNKNOWN),
        stringify(TYPE::CLIENT),
        stringify(TYPE::SERVER)
    };
    
private:
    TYPE _type;
};


struct EnumStringify
{
    /**
    * Get enum type string by value
    */
    template <class EnumType>
    static std::string getEnumTypeName(const EnumType& t, const char (*typeValues)[10])
    {
        std::string s(typeValues[static_cast<int>(t)]);
        return (s.size()) ? s.substr(s.find_last_of(":") + 1) : "";
    }
};

int main()
{
  MyClass a(MyClass::TYPE::CLIENT);
  std::cout << EnumStringify::getEnumTypeName<MyClass::TYPE>(a.type(), MyClass::typeValue).c_str();
}
```

Errors happened:

```
main.cpp:55:90: error: no matching function for call to ‘EnumStringify::getEnumTypeName(MyClass::TYPE, const char* [10])’
   std::cout << EnumStringify::getEnumTypeName<MyClass::TYPE>(a.type(), MyClass::typeValue).c_str();
                                                                                          ^
main.cpp:45:21: note: candidate: template static std::string EnumStringify::getEnumTypeName(const EnumType&, const char (*)[10])
  static std::string getEnumTypeName(const EnumType& t, const char (*typeValues)[10])
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:45:21: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:55:90: note:   cannot convert ‘MyClass::typeValue’ (type ‘const char* [10]’) to type ‘const char (*)[10]’
   std::cout << EnumStringify::getEnumTypeName<MyClass::TYPE>(a.type(), MyClass::typeValue).c_str();
```

Please help me to make it correct. Maybe with **typedef** would be better?

Comment: Based on the *type ‘const char* [10]’) to type ‘const char (*)[10]’* in the error message, it looks like `const char (*typeValues)[10]` looks too much like an array of function pointers (or something like that). What happens if you remove the brackets around `(*typeValues)`?

Comment: yes, without brackets it also works. Thanx. But how it should be with typedef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `const char(*name)[]` defines a pointer to an array of `const char`s, not strings.
2. `MyClass::typeValue` is of type `const char* (&)[10]` so it cannot be implicitly converted to a pointer to that array.

This works:

```cpp
class MyClass{
    //...
    constexpr static const char* typeValue[10] = {
        stringify(TYPE::UNKNOWN),
        stringify(TYPE::CLIENT),
        stringify(TYPE::SERVER)
    };
    
private:
    TYPE _type;
};


struct EnumStringify
{
    /**
    * Get enum type string by value
    */
    template <class EnumType>
    static std::string getEnumTypeName(const EnumType& t, const char* const (&typeValues )[10])
    {
        std::string s(typeValues[static_cast<int>(t)]);
        return (s.size()) ? s.substr(s.find_last_of(":") + 1) : "";
    }
};
```

I also added `constexpr` and pass the value by `const` reference since you do not want to change it.

My advice would to be use `std::array`, it alleviates all the issues with passing arrays around.

### `std::array` solution

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

#define stringify(name) #name

struct MyClass
{
    enum class TYPE
    {
        UNKNOWN = 0,
        CLIENT,
        SERVER
    };
    
    MyClass(TYPE t)
        :_type(t)
    {       
    }
    
    TYPE type()
    {
        return _type;
    }

    constexpr static auto typeValue = std::array{
        stringify(TYPE::UNKNOWN),
        stringify(TYPE::CLIENT),
        stringify(TYPE::SERVER)
    };
    
private:
    TYPE _type;
};

struct EnumStringify
{
    template <class EnumType, class Array>
    static std::string getEnumTypeName(const EnumType& t, const Array& array)
    {
        std::string s(array[static_cast<int>(t)]);
        return (s.size()) ? s.substr(s.find_last_of(":") + 1) : "";
    }
};

int main()
{
  MyClass a(MyClass::TYPE::CLIENT);
  std::cout << EnumStringify::getEnumTypeName(a.type(), MyClass::typeValue).c_str();
}
```

### Template variable

If I were to write such code, I would use template variable which the user can specialize to provide strings for their own enums:

```cpp
//

// "Stringify Library"
#define stringify(name) #name

struct MissingEnumTable{};
template<class Enum>
constexpr MissingEnumTable stringified_enum{};

template <class E>
static std::string getEnumTypeName(const E& t)
{
    static_assert(!std::is_same_v<decltype(stringified_enum<E>),MissingEnumTable>,
                  "Enum E is missing stringified_enum table specialization.");
    std::string s(stringified_enum<E>[static_cast<int>(t)]);
    return (s.size()) ? s.substr(s.find_last_of(":") + 1) : "";
}

// END

// Library user
//  - Provide strings for a custom array
enum class TYPE
{
    UNKNOWN = 0,
    CLIENT,
    SERVER
};

template<>
constexpr auto stringified_enum<TYPE> = std::array{
        stringify(TYPE::UNKNOWN),
        stringify(TYPE::CLIENT),
        stringify(TYPE::SERVER)
    };

int main()
{
  std::cout << getEnumTypeName(TYPE::UNKNOWN).c_str();
}
```

Comment: and if define **typeValue** and **getEnumTypeName** throught typedef? how it looks like?

Comment: `getEnumTypeName` is a template function, it cannot be typedefed, it does not make much sense anyway right? It's not a type, its a function (template). `typeValue` is also not a type.

Comment: I mean to define `const char* typeValue[10]` with typedef

Comment: Sure, `using type= const char*[10];` works but `std::array` is safer option.

Comment: and how to make it properly with arrays? There will be different classes with different array sizes and I want to pass any array  to method `getEnumTypeName`

Comment: @Pasha Yes, that is possible by just "abstracting the type away" into a template parameter, let the compiler throw errors if the body does not compile. See the second example, also I added a snippet how I would go about writing this functionality.

Comment: yes, it works as expected. Thank you very much.